# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS rails cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-push

After cap deploy I am getting an error

```
 Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...lings';src:url(": expected ")", was "<%= asset_path"..."
```

Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Add an `.erb` to the file, where the exception is raised.

Comment: Thanks for response. But my all css file is css.erb